# Clean close-down of sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am using a connection pool and threads to talk to Oracle.

Sometimes my application exits when the daemon threads are mid-flight with long-running queries with open connections.

After a while, I get `ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit` errors when my application starts, because the open connections were not closed properly when the application shut down.

When an application shuts down, how can I get all open connections to the DB to be closed, even if they are in-use by a daemon thread?

Comment: this is with cx_oracle?  cx_oracle should be closing them down when they're garbage collected.  if that's not happening, and your app is just outright crashing (like segfaulting or core dumping), nothing is really going to help aside from fixing those catastrophic failures from happening.